# Bootstrap CSS - Video page - layout headaches

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a page for a video feed from YouTube. The feed itself is fine, I'm picking up the videos without any issues, but I'm trying to use Bootstrap CSS to layout the page in a responsive way so that it renders well on any device, but I can't get my head around Bootstrap's confusing layout grids.

When I grab the feed from YouTube I'm also grabbing the multiple thumbnail images that they provide with each video. In a nutshell I have a large, medium and small image for each. I'd like to use these thumbnails (each wrapped in an anchor and linking to the actual video on YouTube, but that part is out of the scope of this question). I just want to arrange the thumbnails on the page roughly as follows:

- Tiny screen (i.e. a phone):
  Small image - 1 per row - so that I get a stack of single images
- Small screen (i.e. a small tablet or netbook):
  Small image - 2 or 3 per row - in a grid/table formation
- Medium screen (i.e. a bigger tablet in landscape mode)
  medium image - 2 or 3 per row - in a grid/table formation
- Large screem (i.e. normal monitor, full size laptop)
  medium image - 4 or 5 per row - in a grid/table formation
- X-Large screen (i.e large/wide screen monitor)
  large image - 3,4 or 5 per rows (depending on just how big the monitor is)

I'm getting mixed up with responsive grids where bootstrap actually resizes the image, and using media queries to switch between the different sized thumbnails. It's starting to bake my head a bit, and to be honest I'm not even sure if what I've described above is the best layout, so any advice on any of this would be appreciated.

Here's where I'm at so far. This is a MVC page, which has C# inline code mixed in. If that makes it too confusing I'll remove it with an edit, but I just to post what I've got in it's raw form to start. Suffice to say the @foreach line is a loop and everything within the curly braces is repeated per image:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach (var mix in ((List<Studio96.Models.DjMix>)Model.Contents))
    {
        <div class="video">
            <div class="s col-md-2">
                <div style="max-width: @(mix.SmallThumb.Width)px" class="thumbnail nomargin">
                    <a href="@mix.Link">
                        <div class="title">@mix.Title</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="thumbnail nomargin">
                        <a href="@mix.Link">
                            <img src="@mix.SmallThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="m col-md-2">
                <div style="max-width: @(mix.MediumThumb.Width)px" class="thumbnail nomargin">
                    <a href="@mix.Link">
                        <div class="title">@mix.Title</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="thumbnail nomargin">
                        <a href="@mix.Link">
                            <img src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="l col-md-3">
                <div style="width: @(mix.MediumThumb.Width)px;" class="thumbnail nomargin">
                    <a href="@mix.Link">
                        <div class="title">@mix.Title</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="thumbnail nomargin">
                        <a href="@mix.Link">
                            <img src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        </a>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="x col-md-6"> 
                <div style="max-width: @(mix.LargeThumb.Width)px" class="thumbnail nomargin">
                    <a href="@mix.Link">
                        <div class="title">@mix.Title</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="thumbnail nomargin">
                        <a href="@mix.Link">
                            <img src="@mix.LargeThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS...

```
.video {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video .title {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px
}

.video .nomargin {
    margin-bottom: 1px !important;
}

@media (max-width:349px) {
    .video .s { display: block }
    .video .m { display: none }
    .video .l { display: none }
    .video .x { display: none }
}

@media (min-width:350px) and (max-width:749px) {
    .video .s { display: none }
    .video .m { display: block }
    .video .l { display: none }
    .video .x { display: none }
}

@media (min-width:750px) and (max-width:959px) {
    .video .s { display: none }
    .video .m { display: none }
    .video .l { display: block }
    .video .x { display: none }
}

@media (min-width:960px) {
    .video .s { display: none }
    .video .m { display: none }
    .video .l { display: none }
    .video .x { display: block }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your .s .m .l and .x.

Bootstrap has hidden-[size] or visible-[size] so you can see visible-xs. which will as the name suggest be visible on extra small screen.

For the layouth use col-[size]-[1-12] to display 50% width element on medium size screen use .col-md-6. so 100 / 12 * 6 = 50% (do the math for the rest :) )

Hope this helps

**edit: **

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2"> <!--how big/many columns-->
            <div style="max-width: @(mix.MediumThumb.Width)px" class="thumbnail nomargin">
                <a href="@mix.Link">
                    <div class="title">@mix.Title</div>
                </a>
                <div class="thumbnail nomargin">
                    <a href="@mix.Link">
                        <!--different images for diferent size-->
                        <img class="vissible-lg" src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        <img class="vissible-md" src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        <img class="vissible-sm" src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                        <img class="vissible-xs" src="@mix.MediumThumb.Url" alt="@mix.Title" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Could you possibly give me an example to explain what you mean?